# Checking internet connection transferring data or not on android

Tags: android, gprs

I want to check if data connectivity(EDGE) is transferring the data or not in android?

Answer (score 0):

use the getDataActivity() of TelephonyManager
If its value is non-zero then there's network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);